# How can we run offline tests using cypress in a PWA application?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cypress

In our `Progressive Web App`[PWA]  we have to test a couple of `Offline` business cases using Cypress.

When the users are in offline, they can still perform most of the normal business operations and when they become online, everything will be pushed and sync with the server.
*The user is logged in with the Microsoft credentials (SSO)*

Any idea how we can run these offline tests using cypress? 
Can we use `puppeteer` for testing the offline case?

```
context('Actions',()=>{

    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.reload(true);
      cy.loadTokens();
      cy.saveLocalStorage();
      cy.visit('https://sometest.windows.net/home');
    })
    it('Verify the creation of something is possible in Offline',()=>{
      Cypress.currentTest.retries(1);
      cy.viewport(2000, 1000);
      cy.wait(3000);
      // In offline as a user, I need to perform some of the normal business functions here...

    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Puppeteer you have the option to talk to DevTools and throttling the page with [CDPSession class](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.17.0&show=api-class-cdpsession), consider the following example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  // Create a new tab
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  // Connect to Chrome DevTools
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()

  // Set throttling property
  await client.send('Network.emulateNetworkConditions', {
    'offline': true,
    'downloadThroughput': 200 * 1024 / 8,
    'uploadThroughput': 200 * 1024 / 8,
    'latency': 20
  })

  // Navigate and take a screenshot
  await page.goto('https://sometest.windows.net/home')
  await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'})
  await browser.close()
})
```

Comment: So if we perform throttling of page, can we the user access the page and fod the actions in offline ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, as above if I create a method as `offlineLogin()` and add in `commands.js` file also include some of the actions to perform in that method, will that actions be displayed in the web page when he become online next time ?

Comment: Just implement a simple example and figure out what happens.

Comment: I have created a sample `offlineLoginCheck()` in commands.js file and add the above puppetter code also include  ` require('puppeteer')` in index.js file. Cypress doesn't like it and error displayed `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\work\UiTests\node_modules\puppeteer\utils\browser\WebSocket' from 'C:\work\UiTests`

Comment: I have called the `offlineLoginCheck()` in my test and it complains with the above error,

Comment: I don't have an idea about how you install Puppeteer and how context execution worked under Cypress, give me link?

Comment: I have installed puppeteer via npm and its pupeeter is available under node_modules folder.. I have my modified script `offline-login-check.js` in test root folder. From command prompt I am trying to run `node offline-login-check.js`

Comment: It gives following error ..Timeout or other error:  Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED at https://sometestsite.net/
    at navigate (C:\work\UiTests\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:121:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\work\UiTests\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:110:27)
    at Page.goto (C:\work\UiTests\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:629:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\work\UiTests\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:23)
    at puppeteer.launch.then

Comment: Where do I go and see the screenshot  `await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'})` in puppeteer ?

Comment: @soccerway Screenshot can be found near your test script toy invoke) Please mark my answer at least as helpful, thank you.